# Receiving Error Code 3, http_status null, body null, exception state 2

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic project for uploading videos/images.

Every time on the initial run, it uploads without a hitch. But, on the second file upload and everyone thereafter - I receive this error:

> ERROR:
>   {"code":3,"source":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.videocap/files/videolocal.mp4","target":"/upload.php","http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":"state:
>   2"}

The code is as such,

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.quality=10;
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName="videodame.mp4";
options.chunkedMode=false;
options.mimeType="video/mp4";
options.trustAllHosts=true;
var headers={'Connection':'close'};
options.headers = headers;

$cordovaFileTransfer.upload("http://76.181.104.114/Dame/upload.php", videomp4, options).then(function(result) {
                console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
                console.log("SCOPECLIPmp4: " + $scope.clip + '.mp4');
        }, function(err) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }, function (progress) {
                //console.log("PROG:" + progress);
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please ask if extra info is required! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution, had a duplicate variable that was causing the second video to reference variables from the first video.

I'm a genius, it's whatever.